# wiring outside lights and adding a double socket

Tags: lighting, outdoor, socket

I've just wired up a daisy chain of GU10 LED fence lights in my garden and my plan was to run my 2.5mm cable from the house to an outdoor light switch and then carry on to the first light. My wife then reminded me that i needed a socket at the bottom of the garden (which is why i'm using 2.5 and not 1.5mm cable) so now my plan is thus. Run a cable from the house to an outdoor connection box where (utilising wago's) the circuit will then go 1 way to the light switch and the other way for the double socket. I spoke to my electrician briefly about it and he said i needed to go to the light first and then to the switch but these lights are only small and fitting 2 cables in the back was a ball ache, let alone 3. The double socket will be used once in a blue moon to power a projector or speaker maybe and is the 10th socket on the circuit in total (20A mcb in the CU). I know my method isn't to whatever the code may be this week, but in theory it works (in my head anyway). Does anyone else see a issue or can help if this is going to go sideways?[image: basic idea of what i plan to do]

Comment: Are you required to have a Ring? I ask since you specify metric wire sizes if a ring is required your change would work but would violate code.

Comment: If fitting cables into a box is a problem, than, in all likelihood, you've exceeded the fill limits for the box and need to have a larger box. You may not care about code, but the insurance company sure will if there's ever a fire. The police may as well.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this works. The switch comes before the lights, and the split off to the receptacles comes before the switch. There are other ways to do this, but this is also correct and easy to understand.

I'm not sure what that electrician means.

As for code: you should *ALWAYS* stick to code. It's for your safety and also to make sure you are covered by your home insurance.

What country/region ?

- Apply the right type of cabling for the breaker (20A cable is fine on a 15A breaker, but likely not required at all)
- use a GFCI breaker, or
- put a GFCI receptacle on the junction box, and run the lighting and the intended receptacle off the "load" side of the GFCI receptacle.
- apply proper grounding back to the panel
- where applicable use outdoor cabling or conduit, outdoor junction boxes and outdoor/covered receptacles and switches

Go to the electrical/hardware store, inquire about the right outdoor parts, watch some youtube videos on this topic, and come back here with more questions and pictures when needed.

There are some great **electricians** here that are more than happy to provide concise input provided you have clear and informed questions with pictures.

And then enjoy a wonderful and safe summer on your deck/patio with a lit backyard and music & movies.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have now completed the job with the small alteration of swapping the junction box for an RCD. This way if there was an issue with the wiring or the socket then it would only go back to the RCD and trip the main fuse at the consumer unit. Thankfully the switch on went well and my brownie points have been added from the wife. Thanks :-)

Comment: @ScottParker-Copestick I'm glad it worked. Remember to upvote the answers you like.